# global constant in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I want to make a global constant that can be seen by all modules. I have tried different ways to declare a variable in the top module. However other modules don't recognize it.

In my top module I have the following:

```
`define MODELSIM 0
```

When I'm in Xilinx, I will set MODELSIM to 0. When I'm in Modelsim, I will set it to 1.

In other modules in other files, I will have the following:

```
  if(MODELSIM)
```

so that different things will happen depending on whether I'm in Modelsim or Xilinx.

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? If it's a constant, maybe consider using a `define statement

Comment: I'm trying to set a constant because there are parts of code that work in Modelsim but not in Xilinx. I want to be able to use a global constant so that I can control those parts and set the constant depending on whether I'm in Modelsim or Xilinx.

Comment: It sounds like you want `define

Comment: Sounds like it. But I can't reference it from the other module by using top.globalconstant.

Answer (score 7):

There are a few things to be aware of. Getting the simple one out of the way first, references to preprocessor macros in verilog must be prefixed with a backtick, i.e.:

```
if (`MODELSIM)
```

The verilog standard specifies that tick-defines have global scope, meaning that if you define `MODELSIM` in the first file that is compiled, that definition will apply to all subsequent files. However, I believe Modelsim compiles each file in a separate compilation unit, so the safest thing to do is to create a `mydesign.vh` header with your macro definitions, and `` `include `` it in each verilog file. `` `define `` works at the level of the source text. There is no association between a `` `define `` and specific module, and no way to access a `` `define `` by scope.

A few stylistic notes:

1. If you are trying to make a distinction between simulation and synthesis, it is standard to use the `SYNTHESIS` macro for this. Many synthesis tools will define it automatically. Be judicious about making things conditional on synthesis. Since it is intentionally causing your simulation to differ from your synthesized result, it's an easy way to shoot yourself in the foot.
2. For simple flags, it may be better to use values of 1/undef rather than 1/0. Defining things to be zero can result in problems if you later write `` `ifdef MACRO ``.

Answer (score 3):

For synthesizable code, there is no such thing as a global variable. You must route any such signals through your design.

Comment: Hmm...  Isn't _constant_ the opposite of _variable_?

Comment: I liked your original answer and think it's worth having around, even if the question is a bit amorphous.

Answer (score 2):

Just prefix it with the name of the top-level module.

```
module top;
  integer myglobalvar;
endmodule

module any;
  initial $display(top.myglobalvar);
endmodule
```

Comment: Then Xilinx does not support standard Verilog.  If you are asking about Xilinx then you should mention that in the question.

Comment: Out of module references are generally not synthesisable.

Comment: If define is used then how is the variable referenced from another module?